# Search for substring in string literal using regular expressions gives wrong results

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I tried to find string literals containing the character sequence DMS in Visual Studio 2015. For this I used this regualar expression:

```
"[^"]*DMS[^"]*"
```

To my surprise the search results not only contains correct hits but also hits like

```
/// <param name="context">Service Context.</param>
```

Can someone explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"[^"]*DMS[^"]*"` can have unexpected matches because `[^"]*` may span multiple lines, see example here: https://regex101.com/r/fgVpFc/1

A good workaround is to limit the character classes only to your expected characters, for example:

- [`"[^"\n]*DMS[^"\n]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/fgVpFc/2) - Don't allow multiline matches.
- [`"\S*DMS\S*"`](https://regex101.com/r/fgVpFc/3) - Don't allow spaces at all.
- [`"[\w.]*DMS[\w.]*"`](https://regex101.com/r/fgVpFc/4) - Allow only alphanumeric characters and dots.